# RFIC Layout Transmission Line Considerations

Tags: integrated-circuit

In doing RFIC Layout (that is above 1GHz on chip), when do you use transmission lines as interconnect (CPW, microstrip, etc.) versus just regular interconnect?  What is the rule of thumb?

Comment: Before you get whacked for a "wide open questions", I will seed starting answers. The wave length of 1Ghz is approximately "3 * 10^8 meters" / "1GHz". Generally, as I briefly learned, 1/(nambda * 4) is where you would start getting worried more about transmission line, not sure I am. I am a guy who try to avoid RF. And I use modules and modems, placing Antena (whatever kind) as close as possible and according to the datasheet.

Comment: That's a roundabout way of saying that the wavelength of a 1GHz signal is about 30cm and the rule-of-thumb is that when the interconnect length exceeds 1/4 of that or 7.5cm you need to start considering transmission line effects.  Unless your IC is unusually large or you have some other special considerations, you likely don't need to worry about it too much.

Comment: @jwh20, 1 GHz gives about 300 mm wavelength in air. In gallium arsenide (\$\epsilon_R=12.8\$) it's only ~83 mm. We might worry about transmission line effects with a line length of 1/10 or more of the wavelength (By 1/4 wavelength you're already looking at some potentially pretty severe effects), so 8.3 mm. In the RF world it's certainly possible to have a chip dimension of 8 or 9 mm. This is kind of on the edge of where you'd need to worry about it, but it's where you should start questioning if you need to worry about it.

Comment: But for Silicon the ER=3.6 roughly right ? So for 300mm/2 = 150mm or so in Silicon vs. GaAs ?

Answer (score 1):

IPC-2251 defines a method for computing this, however your performance specs determine the choice of variables on return loss or transmission loss, impedance ratio etc.

This range is from \$\lambda/4\$ to \$\lambda/20\$ for the total loop path.